# Определить член предложения

Tags: синтаксис, словосочетания, члены-предложения

Каким членом предложения является "всех пород" в словочетании "деревья всех пород"?

Comment: _Деревья **КАКИЕ?**_  К каким членам предложения ставится такой вопрос?

Comment: **Член предложения** не может быть в **словосочетании**, не так ли?

Comment: @Niemand может.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 2):

**Правильная формулировка вопроса**: Какова синтаксическая функция  сочетания "всех пород" в словосочетании "деревья всех пород"?

**Всех пород** – это **нечленимое сочетание**, которое выполняет функцию одного члена предложения (**несогласованного определения**).

**Грамматическая справка**

1) **Синтаксическая функция** – это роль слова или формы слова в синтаксической конструкции (**в словосочетании или предложении**). Примерами синтаксических функций являются: функции членов предложения (подлежащее, дополнение, обстоятельство и др.), функции вводных слов и др.

[Понятие синтаксической функции. Синтаксическая позиция | studopedia.ru](http://studopedia.ru/12_413_ponyatie-sintaksicheskoy-funktsii-sintaksicheskaya-pozitsiya.html)

2) **Существуют целый ряд нечленимых сочетаний определенной структуры, например:** пять столов, никто из нас, сильнейший из зверей, мы с другом, метафоры (зерно истины, лес рук, взрыв аплодисментов).

В данном случае нечленимость сочетания связана  с параметрами или другими абстрактными словами, которые сами по себе не несут достаточной информации: низкая температура, средний рост, вид спорта, все **породы** и др.

Comment: *Правильная формулировка вопроса:* - а это вообще  другой вопрос, а не правильная формулировка.

Comment: Можно ответить на вопрос, если он корректно поставлен. Я НЕ ВИЖУ здесь предложения, поэтому не могу  говорить о  членах предложения.  Но есть возможность определить  синтаксическую роль  слов в приведенном словосочетании, поэтому я отвечаю на этот вопрос.

Comment: Вопрос вполне корректно поставлен. Но совсем не так, как вы переделали. А в чем некорректность-то? Aer внятно не ответил, а мне гадать не хочется. А что нет предложения, так это и не важно. В любом предложении "всех пород" будет определением.

Comment: Каким членом предложения является X в словосочетании Y - это неверный вопрос,  а всё остальное (про любое предложение) надо додумывать.  "Каким членом предложения является слово?" и  "Определить синтаксическую функцию слова в предложении" - это синонимичные выражения, но второе выражение универсально. Синтаксическая роль определяется в данном случае на уровне словосочетания и далее при построении предложения не меняется.

Comment: Вот и надо работать со словосочетанием. А если это не получается, то нужно задать предложение: "В лесу растут деревья всех пород",  или "На изготовление мебели идут деревья всех пород", или что еще можно сказать о деревьях всех пород. А потом коротко спросить "Каким членом предложения является "всех пород?", предварительно высказав свое мнение.

Comment: *это неверный вопрос* - Вы знаете, я спрашивал у двух практикующих учителей русского языка, они подтвердирли, что вы придираетесь. Вопрос вполне корректен, не надо его его менять по своей прихоти. Могу еще и у преподавателя МГУ спросить. Но считаю излишним. Я никак не могу понять причины вашего неприятия, вот в чем беда... *надо додумывать* - не надо ничего додумывать. Что вам мешает ответить на вопрос именно на тот вопрос, который задан? Не про "синтаксическую функцию" (о которой автор может и не знать), а именно про член предложения?

Comment: Ответ очень простой: нельзя найти члены предложения там, где нет предложения. (А где, кстати, наши педагоги-профессионалы, хорошо бы услышать их мнение). Человек должен точно выражать свои мысли - именно этому нужно обучать детей в школе. А то получается такой разговор: да-да, примерно я понимаю, о чем ты меня спрашиваешь, сейчас отвечу.

Comment: *нельзя найти члены предложения там, где нет предложения* - совершенно не обязательно иметь полное предложение. А приводимого кусочка в данном случае достаточно. Ладно, чувствую это напрасная трата времени.

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос поставлен не совсем корректно. Вы же сами говорите о *члене **предложения***, но спрашиваете о **словосочетании**; член предложе́ния — синтаксическая функция слов и словосочетаний **в предложениях** ([Википедия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)).

Тем не менее, если говорить о синтаксической роли слов *всех пород* в приведенном словосочетании, то их стоит признать несогласованным **определением**, так как они сообщают о признаке предмета.

Comment: *говорите о члене предложения, но спрашиваете о словосочетании* - не вижу проблем. Вы придираетесь вслед за Niemand'ом.

Comment: @behemothus звучит не очень хорошо "член предложения в словосочетании". Это совершенно разные синтаксические единицы. Но школьная терминология не позволяет, видимо, употребить другой термин, поэтому я и сделал замечание.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52479/discussion-on-answer-by-aer---).

Comment: *Это совершенно разные синтаксические единицы* - Это не аргумент.

Answer (score 0):

Определением. Отвечает на вопрос "какие?".

Добавить тут особо нечего. Вот простенькая табличка.
http://all-biography.ru/russkiy-yazyk/roditelnyy-padezh

По поводу "некорректности" вопроса. 
"Словосочетание" совсем не исключает возможности в нем отдельных членов предложения. 
https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5
Другое дело, что само использование такого термина тут является излишним. Но это именно избыточность, никак не некорректность.

(+)
Модератор убирает комментарии, которых сам же просит... ))) Пишу здесь.
Какая-то ерунда пошла... Остаётся только предположить, что Aer и Sibylla неверно понимают вопрос.

Я не вижу никаких причин считать, что автор путает "член предложения" и "словосочетание". Возможно дело в неправильной трактовке предлога "в". Автор не подразумевает, что "член предложения" - элемент словосочетания. Хотя его, автора, видимо, в этом упрекают уже трое. По-другому я эти претензии не могу объяснить.

На самом деле совершенно справедливо полагает, что в словосочетании есть отдельные слова, которые могут быть (вернее сказать - обязаны) членами предложения. 
Путаница - на совести критиков.

Можно, конечно, другой предлог употребить.
***Каким членом предложения является "всех пород", входящее в словосочетание "деревья всех пород"?***
или
***Каким членом предложения является "всех пород" из словосочетания "деревья всех пород"?***

Но это ж надо было предполагать, что твою мысль так извратят... Мне бы в голову не пришло, что можно понять так превратно... Хотя не знаю... Может, и не в этом дело...

Comment: Непонятно, какие "модератор убирает комментарии, которых сам же просит". Будьте добры, уточняйте какие именно. В противном случае — не дезинформируйте других пользователей.

Comment: @Aer, Вы убираете комментарии в чат.